# $\hat{\theta}_u$ unbiased for $\theta$, $\hat{\theta}_b = (1+\alpha)\hat{\theta}_u$. $\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_b) < \text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)$

Tags: statistics, estimation

Suppose $\hat{\theta}_u$ is unbiased for $\theta$, and $\hat{\theta}_b = (1+\alpha)\hat{\theta}_u$.

I have already shown that 
$$\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_b) = (1+\alpha)^2\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)+\alpha^2\theta^2$$
and that 
$$\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_b) < \text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u) \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{-2\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)}{\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)+\theta^2} < \alpha < 0\text{.}$$
However, the final solution I am provided is as follows:
$$\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_b) < \text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u) \Longleftrightarrow-2<\dfrac{-2\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)}{\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)+\theta^2} < \alpha < 0\text{.}$$
**How do we obtain the $-2$ bound for $\alpha$**?

**My attempt**: The only way that $$-2 < \dfrac{-2\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)}{\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)+\theta^2}$$
is if 
$$\dfrac{\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)}{\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)+\theta^2} > 1$$
or
$$\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u) > \text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}_u)+\theta^2$$
which doesn't seem to be true... because $\theta^2 > 0$, so if anything, the inequality should be reversed. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're cancelling negative numbers, which will flip the inequality...

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Doh -_-. Thanks

Comment: Happens to the best of us, mate. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathrm{MSE}(\hat\theta_u)$ and $\theta^2>0$, you certainly have $\mathrm{MSE}(\hat\theta_u)\big/(\mathrm{MSE}(\hat\theta_u)+\theta^2)\le1$ so $-1\le-\mathrm{MSE}(\hat\theta_u)\big/(\mathrm{MSE}(\hat\theta_u)+\theta^2)$ so $$
-2 \le \frac{-2 \mathrm{MSE}(\hat\theta_u)}{\mathrm{MSE}(\hat\theta_u)+\theta^2}.$$